# Hit detection on a Collada object?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have looked through the examples on http://threejs.org. I have not seen any hit detection related to `ColladaLoader` objects. Everything there is related to basic mesh shapes.

Is hit detection on Collada objects possible? If so, what would the syntax look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the links I've found dealing with `mouse picking` objects in `THREE.JS.` The first one or two are most likely outdated.

http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/01/17/dom-events-in-3d-space/

http://voxelent.com/html/beginners-guide/1727_08/ch8_Picking_Scene_Final.html

http://jensarps.de/2013/10/29/mouse-picking-collada-models-with-three-js-part-ii/

Jens Arps wrote a great article on this topic. According to the article, a custom `THREE.Raycaster` was necessary for `Collada Object` detection.

As of **THREE.JS r62**, this is no longer necessary. Mouse picking requires a **Raycaster**, **Projector**, and **Vector3**. Jens Arps's **[latest article](http://jensarps.de/2013/10/29/mouse-picking-collada-models-with-three-js-part-ii/)** covers the necessary steps. It was slightly difficult to follow along at first and the example has a `FirstPersonControls` camera that takes time getting used to.

After examining [the code](https://raw.github.com/jensarps/webgl_experiments/master/collada_picking_ray_r62.html), I was able to select and manipulate `Collada Objects`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_octree_raycasting ?

It seems to be what you are going after.

[***This link***](http://jensarps.de/2012/04/10/how-to-make-three-js-ray-caster-detect-collada-objects/) has a tutorial on Collada objects detected with `THREE.JS RAY CASTER`. You would need to modify the `Ray Class` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

`ColladaLoader` and all others loaders import objects from their specific formats to a regular `THREE.Mesh`

Therefore, there is no special code needed for hit detection against a collada-imported mesh.

That also means if your code work with a collada-imported mesh, it will work with any other source format.

Comment: see Three.js Examples on Picking and GPU picking ;)